# Redirect user back to registration page but keep their filled in form in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a registration.php page and another registration_checker_page.php.

If username and / or email is taken after they submit, then it'll redirect them back to the previous (registration) page.

But then their filled in data is lost. Is there a way to redirect them without clearing their data?

```
if(mysql_num_rows($queryUser) > 0){
   echo '<p><div id="redirect"/></p>';
   }

function  redir {
code ... location.href = "registration.php";
}
```

**Edit:** By filled data it is first name, username, postcode etc. But other information like password etc will be removed.

Comment: Just store the values in their session and then repopulate the form if those values exist

Comment: If I open a session for registration, and if they successfully register then what happens to the login session I have? Wouldn't it conflict? PS it creates a login session after they've logged in*

Comment: Sessions can be created and edited at any time. Like any array, you can remove the values after they login. Or any time you want. You can also have different keys for different areas of your site to keep values from conflicting.

Comment: Why are you using to separate scripts for this anyway? Use _one_ script to display the form _and_ do the validation – then you can output the form with the already entered and send data pre-filled as many times as validation fails.

Comment: John Conde Oh right. Cheers.

@CBroe You recommend me deleting the registration_checker php, and move it to the register.php? I do have form validation with JS on the register php, but it's only for reg exp checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  session or cookie for same

```
if(mysql_num_rows($queryUser) > 0){
echo '<p><div id="redirect"/></p>';
}

function  redir() {
$userName = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

setcookie("userName", $userName, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
setcookie("emial", $email, time()+3600);

code ... location.href = "registration.php";
}
```

And at your form

```
<input type="text" name="userName"  value="<?php echo isset($_COOKIE['userName']) ? $_COOKIE['userName']:'' ?>">
<input type="text" name="email"  value="<?php echo isset($_COOKIE['email']) ? $_COOKIE['email']:'' ?>">
```

You can above same with using session.

Hope this will help

Comment: Would I just replace $_COOKIE with $_SESSION in the form? As I want to destroy session once they have successfully registered. As when they login (after successful register) it opens another session.

Comment: yes replace $_COOKIE with $_SESSION but also do change at setcookie("userName", $userName, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
setcookie("emial", $email, time()+3600);

replace above line using
$_SESSION['useName'] = $userName;
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;

also dont forget to start session

Answer (score 1):

The *best* way to solve this, in MNSHO[1], is to make sure those values are never lost in the first place.

Lets assume, for the same of discussion, that you have a field in your HTML called 'username'

If you are using a `GET` (or a regular redirect), you can include `username` as part of the 
querystring, so it is available on the registration page.

```
window.location.href = "registration.php?username=" . $_REQUEST(username);
```

**And then, on your registration page:**

```
<input name="username" type="text">
```

What you'd want to do is look and see if you have an existing value that came in.

```
<?php
$usernameValue = "";
if (isset($_REQUEST['username'])) {
  $usernameValue = $_REQUEST['username'];
}

// Typing on the fly, I may have the type of quotation marks
// flipped around.  N
echo '<input name="username" type="text" value="$usernameValue">';
// or this...
echo "<input name='username' type='text' value='$usernameValue'>";

?>
```

Now, if you are redirecting to this page from another...

[1] My Not-So-Humble Opinion

Answer (score 0):

You could save them a get variable and append that to the file you are referring them too, or do it server side and save them by a temporary ID.

First possibility:

`location.href="registraion.php?e=thisdudes@ema.il&u=thisdude"`

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX to check for duplicate username/email immediately after the textbox loses focus and notify the user accordingly. That is how modern pages do it.

Is there a reason why you are waiting for the user to fill the complete form before checking for duplicate username/email?

Comment: The developer shouldn't trust ajax verification Only. Some server side validation is also required. If the server finds a dublicate then there would still be need for a solution to OPs question.

Comment: AJAX verification and server-side validation are different? How?

Comment: The verification With ajax would still be done server side. So far you are correct. But then the validation is easily bypassed by the user. Hence further server side validation is required!

Comment: Yeah as Philip said. For security sake I'd rather server handle all the sensitive data. The AJAX or JS will handle the other validations like checking for correct grammar, validity of email etc.

Comment: That makes sense. Further validation is required.
BUT.
If a user is trying to bypass your AJAX verification, then it is almost certain that this user is malicious.
Why would you want to help this malicious user by saving his form data? I would love to know the reason for doing so.

Comment: There are always malicious users but a site should always consider for all the other users that aren't malicious. You don't want a user to fill in the entire form consisting of 10's of dozens of fields and then reset everything. Only the sensitive fields (password, retype password/email, security questions etc) will be reset - which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Build features for good users; Handle malicious users as `exceptions`.

What I am suggesting is something similar to [Google's sign up page](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp).